# How to add an extra source directory for maven to compile and include in the build jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

In addition to the src/main/java, I am adding a src/bootstrap directory that I want to include in my build process, in other words, I want maven to compile and include the sources there in my build. How!?

Comment: Simple question: Why not moving the source code to src/main/java ? Or create a separate maven project/module which contains the code and define it as dependency.

Comment: In my case I need to add a generated sources folder, which I prefer to reside inside target.

Comment: Alternatively, one might want to place *integration-tests* in directories other than `src/{main,test}/` as told [here](https://dzone.com/articles/integration-tests-with-maven)

Comment: This has also been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/270445/1061929

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use the [Build Helper Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html), e.g:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>some directory</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Does eclipse really recognize such a folder as one of the `buildpath`s for anyone? 'cos it doesn't for me. FWIW, I use `m2e` to import the project.

Comment: Great answer, just to clarify, you should replace your maven-compiler-plugin with the lines from above...

Comment: Works in IntelliJ as well.

Comment: So if (in Eclipse Luna) i added (linked) in my BuildPath (clicking the right mouse button on my MavenProject) a source folder where its directory is "/Users/MyName/Desktop/source", i have to write `<source>/Users/MyName/Desktop/source<source>` ?? And everything goes right?

Comment: I don't know why, but i simply removed the linked source and re-added on the build path and everything has gone right. If I have any other problem I will post that here. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: The question is about Maven, which has no knowledge of (nor should it) of the IDE (e.g., eclipse). Builds should work on Jenkins or whatever build server without any IDE-specific references. The IDE must invoke Maven (build tool) and thus IDE-related questions should probably be taken out separately.

Comment: Eclipse asked me to install a plugin for m2e, the build helper connector. I did it, and the lifecycle error is gone.

Comment: This requires me to move to java 7, this solution does not work for java 6 ?
Or am I missing something ?

Comment: is there a solution without having to install a plugin ?

Comment: `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (execution: add-source, phase: generate-sources)` getting this error

Comment: Can someone explain to me how this is better than recursive make? xD

Answer (score 36):

***NOTE: This solution will just move the java source files to the target/classes directory and will not compile the sources.***

---

#### Update the `pom.xml` as -

```
<project>   
 ....
    <build>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        </resource>
      </resources>
     ...
    </build>
...
</project>
```

Comment: NetBeans picked it up like a charm :)

Comment: Seems you do need to remove the ** exclusion for the added folder on the Eclipse build path though :(

Comment: @Dormouse can you explain please?

Comment: In Eclipse, when you add a resource like this, you need to remove the ** exclusion from the build path for the directory to have it recognize the sources.

Comment: Does not work with IntelliJ, it will see `<resource>` as "Resource" folder but not as "Source" folder, e.g. it won't compile Java source files inside them.

Comment: @AlexanderKlimetschek I did not know that POM is IDE dependent

Comment: I was referring to IntelliJ's Maven support that reads pom files automatically and sets its projects settings accordingly - it will strictly see `<resource>` folders as resource directories, not sources.

Comment: This solution will just move the java source files to the target/classes directory and will *not compile* the sources

Comment: Under what tag should the `build` tag be located?

Comment: `build` usually comes after `project` as shown in the answer @AlikElzin-kilaka

Answer (score 17):

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>../src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
```

also see

[Maven compile with multiple src directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories)

Comment: This overrides the default src/main/java directory. If you want multiple directories, you have to specify the default one as well.

Comment: The question is how to add multiple source directories and you are proposing a method to add only one source directory, which is the opposite of what is asked.

Answer (score 4):

To mark a folder as generated sources, AND have it picked up by IntelliJ, use the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>src/main/generated</generatedSourcesDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I spent an hour searching on how to avoid IntelliJ reverting after I manually marked target/generated-sources as a generated sources folder. The codehaus.mojo plugin didn't work. But this solution did!

Comment: This is exactly what was required for me. I am working with protobuf and it defaults its compiled code in generatedSource dir. For some reason intellij, doesnt implicitly pick the class def files for me to use them in core app class files. I had to give the above plugin to make it look into the target folder. Thanks for this solution. It made a quick work.

Comment: Seems to be the most correct solution. In my case `generatedSourcesDirectory` is `target/generated-sources`.

Answer (score 1):

With recent Maven versions (3) and recent version of the maven compiler plugin (3.7.0), I notice that adding a source folder with the `build-helper-maven-plugin` is not required if the folder that contains the source code to add in the build is located in the `target` folder or a subfolder of it.
It seems that the compiler maven plugin compiles any java source code located inside this folder whatever the directory that contains them.
For example having some (generated or no) source code in `target/a`, `target/generated-source/foo` will be compiled and added in the outputDirectory : `target/classes`.

Answer (score -4):

You can add the directories for your build process like:

```
    ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/bootstrap</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
```

The src/main/java is the default path which is not needed to be mentioned in the pom.xml

Comment: Why the downvotes people? Basically the same answer as saiky0's (which has upvotes) but earlier?

Comment: @Friso because it's not correct. Adding a resource directory will add resources (files copied to `target/classes`, but not compiled). This question is about adding a source directory, which holds files that will be *compiled* into `target/classes`, not copied.