# Tycho Compiler not picking up generated source code

Tags: maven, tycho, generated-code

I am fairly new to the world of maven and tycho, so hopefully this is just something obvious that I am missing. I am trying to build a plugin using tycho but I am unable to get the tycho-compiler-plugin to recognise source code that is generated as a part of the build process.

Here is a copy of a test pom that I've put together to demonstrate:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>rt</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt.webservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tycho-version>0.16.0</tycho-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-ws-code</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

I have a java class in the src folder that references some of the generated source code, which then fails to compile.

If I remove tycho and use the standard maven-compiler-plugin, it automatically picks up the code generated during the build and the java class mentioned above compiles as expected.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tycho compiler plugin uses source dirs configured in build.properties
you have to make sure the generated source dir is referenced in build.properties

http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html#sourceDestDir

Comment: Adding the generated source dir to the build.properties did the trick - thanks.

Comment: Thanks ! Your explaination helped me with a similar problem.

Answer (score -2):

You have to add additional source folders for generated sources, in your case the `wsdl` dir.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui) for help on that.

Tycho will then pick up those additional directories during compile.

Comment: This is not relevant for Tycho