# How to add multiple source directories to pom.xml

Tags: selenium, maven-2, webdriver, testng

I am getting package org.testng.annotations does not exist error when I am trying to compile multiple source directories using maven. I am running webdriver tests and all of my tests are importing import org.testng.annotations. I am using IntelliJ 12 and my src directory looks like this -

src

```
  -->main
     --> java
        --> package1
            --> file1.java
        --> package2
            --> file2.java
  -->test
     --> java
        --> package1
           --> file1.java
           --> file2.java
        --> package2
        --> package3
        --> package4
        --> package5
        --> package6
```

and the build plugin I am using in the pom.xml looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<parent>
    <artifactId>core-xxxxx</artifactId>
    <groupId>core-xxxxx</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>tests</artifactId>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.32.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
       <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/java</source>
                            <source>src/test/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

why am I getting the org.testng.annotations not found error?

Comment: I did take a look here but it does not solve my issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui

Comment: Can you post your full pom file and the full directory structure of your project?

Answer (score 1):

The default layout for a maven project is the following:

```
src
   main
      java
   test
      java
```

within the *src/main/java/* directory the package name for you productive java class source files should added. within the *src/test/java/* the package name for the unit tests java class source files.

And you should *NOT* change the layout if you don't have really really good reasons to do so.

Furthermore redefining the defaults of Maven defaults (target, target/classes, target/test-classes etc.) is against the convention over configuration paradigm.

Be aware that you need to follow a naming [convention for unit tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) which means you unit tests should be named like the following:

```
<includes>
 <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

But in your case I assume that we are talking about integration tests which means you need to use the following [naming convention](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes)

```
<includes>
 <include>**/IT*.java</include>
 <include>**/*IT.java</include>
 <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Apart from that you should now that unit tests in Maven will be executed by the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) whereas the integration tests will be executed by the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

Comment: @khmarbaise-- thanks for your input. the above approach does a clean compile for me (mvn clean compile) but when i run tests with this command mvn clean test -DsuiteFile=resources/test-suites/audioSuite.xml it throws errors that package 2 does not exists which is a package in the first source directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get around the testng annotations not found errors I ended up moving the base class from src/main/java/package1/baseclass.java to src/main/test/package1/baseclass.java and the testng annotations errors resolved