# How to modify pom file to add src/test/java files to maven jar with dependancies

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin, jar-with-dependencies

I need to include src/test/java files to my jar with dependancies. But when I create the jar it fails because it cannot find the classes. Here is the pom section. Any help would be appreciated.
And i compile with: mvn clean assembly:single

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>single</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that? The whole purpose of that test sources directory is that those files are _not_ included in the build.

Comment: Yes I can, I made a guy for testing and I want to be able to run it from the jar. But because its testing it is in src/test/java

Comment: Alternatively, you might put the test GUI into a second module...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use maven resource plugin and mark the src/test/java as additional source

[similar question is asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui)

Answer (score 0):

by default it is not included, you can have greater amount of flexibility with [maven assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) you can use that to generate jar with whatever content you want to put in

Comment: i am using maven assembly plugin, could you provide an example of how I would add src/test/java using maven assembly plugin?

Comment: check this specially `<fileSet>` http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share how I got it to work, although very ugly. To reiterate I wanted to add the test-classes to the class path only when I made my jar with dependancies. What I did:

switched from assembly-pludin to shade-plugin
And moved the .class files i needed from target/test-classes to proper place in the jar

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
    <file>target/test-classes/path/to/class/i/need/file.class</file>
    <resource>in/classpath/destination/of/class/i/need/file.class</resource>
</transformer>
```

its glorified copy paste and did not see a way to do so via directory so did it 1 .class at a time.

Very ugly, not dynamic, and I am still looking for a better way. But for now it will do.