# packagename doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

Tags: spring, maven, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

While deploying my project to a tomcat-server, I get constantly this exception:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marshaller': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.customerdaoservice" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

But it does have an ObjectFactory.class!

Im using Spring, Maven and Jaxb2

My POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.icredit</groupId>
    <artifactId>einvoice</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>einvoice Portlet</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.10.6</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
        <liferay.version>6.2.1</liferay.version>
        <spring.suite.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</spring.suite.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>

                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>BatchDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/batchdaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>BatchDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.batchdaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerAccountDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/customeraccountdaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>CustomerAccountDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.customeraccountdaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/customerdaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>CustomerDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.customerdaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/documentdaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>DocumentDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.documentdaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/documenttemplatedaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>DocumentTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.documenttemplatedaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailStatusDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/emailstatusdaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>EmailStatusDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.emailstatusdaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/emailtemplatedaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>EmailTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.emailtemplatedaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>FileService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/fileservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>FileService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.fileservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>SenderDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>target/senderdaoservice</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>SenderDaoService.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.senderdaoservice</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am literally clueless..

My applicationcontext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="be.icredit.einvoice.service, be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest" />


    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.customerdaoservice"/>
    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
         <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" /> 
         <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" /> 
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="http://localhost:8081/ws-demo/account-balance-service" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Have you added generated class to source? see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25600373/3364187)

Comment: no.. Why is this necessairy? My project builds, via Maven Install, this works good. no compiler errors?

Comment: The generated classes will be created under target folder .. if you want use them you must add to source folder by the previous link that i passed you. "build-helper-maven-plugin"

Comment: The Jaxb2 plugin takes care of this i guess, I was previously recommended to do this, but it was not necessairy they told me, Spring Tool Suite automatically references to them

Comment: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide say that "Target directory for the generated code, target/generated-sources/xjc by default"

Comment: Yes! Thanks. My project didn't clean itself properly, and that was the issue... I'm literally struggling with the Jaxb2 plugin. While using the generated classes, everything that I try works, except for one. But the i've described it over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805166/unmarshalling-error-unexpected-element-uriurl-localobjectname-expected .. Very stressful first days at new job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's check if you have the problem with the Maven build or in the IDE.

You're saying that your build seems to work fine.

- Do you have a simple unmarshalling test which checks that unmarshalling really works? Make one and make sure it works.
- Check the generated `war` - does it have all of the generated class in `WEB-INF/classes`?
- You have several executions, are all of the generated packages present there (in `WEB-INF/classes`)?

When problems with the maven build are ruled out, check your IDE. I think you're using Eclipse:

- Do you see all of the generated directories as Eclipse source folders?
- Does your simple unmarshalling test (see above) work in Eclipse?
- Do you have to configure somehow, which folders are deployed to Tomcat?
- Do you maybe need to redirect compilation target to `WEB-INF/classes`?

There's quite a couple of places this can go wrong. A simple unit test will help check every step to find out what's missing.

As I said before, `maven-jaxb2-plugin` does add your target directory as a compile source root (unless you explicitly configure it out which you don't do). So Maven integration plugins like `m2eclipse` in Eclipse are supposed to add these directories as source folders. Your project is a bit different from the 'normal' setup in a sense that you have a `war` project and multiple executions. But I still think this must work, `maven-jaxb2-plugin` [does pretty standard stuff here](https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/plugin-core/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/RawXJC2Mojo.java):

```
    if (getAddCompileSourceRoot()) {
        getProject().addCompileSourceRoot(getGenerateDirectory().getPath());
    }
```

This is exactly the same what `build-helper-maven-plugin` [does](http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/build-helper-maven-plugin-1.9.1/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/buildhelper/AddSourceMojo.java):

```
this.project.addCompileSourceRoot( source.getAbsolutePath() );
```