# maven-eclipse-plugin additional source directory not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've put in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceIncludes>
            <sourceInclude>target/generated-test-sources/protobuf/java/**</sourceInclude>
        </sourceIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I run:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 install
```

It does not configure `.classpath` to include this directory.

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to achieve this goal:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>target/generated-test-sources/protobuf/java</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Source: [How to add an extra source directory for maven to compile and include in the build jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui)