# Adding source Folders to my Eclipse Project at generate-sources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Before redirecting me to one of the numerous other posts concerning this (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories)), know that I have already tried that.

What I want to do is simple: I have a folder called generated-sources on the same level as src and I want maven to automatically add it to the source directories.

Here is the snippet as it can also be seen in the questions I linked above:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>generated-sources/enums/</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run it, it actually displays the lines

```
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (add-source) @ gui ---
[INFO] Source directory: C:\development\gdg\gui\generated-sources\enums added.
```

Thing is, even if I do this, the source directories don't appear in the Project Explorer and I can't use them as dependencies either.

Note: I am currently using a m2e Connector Plugin and already tried using the `<pluginManagement>` tag. I also already reloaded the Project, yet to no avail.

I am probably just being incredibly stupid again, so thanks for any help.
~Crowley

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a `Maven > Update Project ...`, besides reloading the project.

If that doesn't help, you can always manually add sources to a project: under a project's Properties, in Java Build Path, Sources tab, use the Add Folder button to select your folder.

Comment: I can't believe that I tried this for so long and never even bothered clicking Update Project. (It works now) Thank you kindly.