# Jenkins looking for dependency project package files in its own folder for multi module projects

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, multi-module

I am working on multi module project with one parent and 2 chils. . A is parent , B and C are child modules.
B is dependent on C.

The project build is success locally.. but in jenkins Build is success for only  parent and child module C and its failure for module B.

For module B which is dependent on C, its checking the file imports of C in package B.

EX: import com.example.C.config.appconfig;

Jenkins is checking that file as "B/src/java/AppConfig"

But it should check as the "C/src/java/AppConfig"

As the build is success for A and C respositories they are pushed Nexus Artifacts as well, but still its recognising the same way.Please suggest.

Comment: Please note: [An aggregator is not a parent, a module is not a child (necessarily)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749979/1744774).

Comment: yes got it , I still face the issues in the local build, That classes not found for the class B which is dependent on class C.Please suggest

Comment: Please add (the relevant parts of) your POMs and of your build output to the question.