# How to make idea to recognize generated folder as source root folder?

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I have simple SPring-Bott project with microservices:

```
project/          <-- Root directory
|-- user/         <-- Submodule 1
|-- service2/     <-- Submodule 2
|-- pom.xml       <-- Root POM
```

I'm trying to integrate gRPC and use user service as grpc service to validate jwt token.
User service pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>user</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user</name>
    <description>user</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--                Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--                Database&tools-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v4-driver</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.2.BETA</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>detect</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.59.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                    <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/proto</protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

proto file is:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.iauto.user.rpc;

service AuthServiceRPC {
  rpc ValidateToken (TokenValidationRequestDTO) returns (TokenValidationResponseDTO);
}

message TokenValidationRequestDTO {
  string phone = 1;
  string sms_code = 2;
  string token = 3;
}

message TokenValidationResponseDTO {
  bool is_valid = 1;
}
```

and rpc service class:

```
@Service
@GRpcService
public class AuthServiceRPC extends AuthServiceRPCGrpc.AuthServiceRPCImplBase {
    public void validateToken(TokenValidationRequestDTO request, StreamObserver<TokenValidationResponseDTO> responseObserver) {
        boolean isValid = true;

        TokenValidationResponseDTO response = TokenValidationResponseDTO.builder()
                .isValid(isValid)
                .build();

        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

In service2 I need to call user service.
its pom:

4.0.0

com.test
test
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<artifactId>service2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>service2</name>
<description>test</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <!--        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>-->
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Project modules dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.iauto</groupId>
        <artifactId>user</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies -->
    <!--        <dependency>-->
    <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
    <!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>-->
    <!--        </dependency>-->

    <!-- WebSocket Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--        testing-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--        utils-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v4-driver</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.BETA</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>detect</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.59.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/proto</protoSourceRoot>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

rpc client:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class AuthServiceRPCClient {
    @Value("${auth.service.host}")
    private String authServiceRPCHost;

    @Value("${auth.service.port}")
    private int authServiceRPCPort;
    private final AuthServiceRPCGrpc.AuthServiceRPCBlockingStub authServiceStub;

    public AuthServiceRPCClient() {
        log.info("AuthService host: {}", authServiceRPCHost);
        log.info("AuthService port: {}", authServiceRPCPort);

        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8180)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
//        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(authServiceRPCHost, authServiceRPCPort)
//                .usePlaintext()
//                .build();

        authServiceStub = AuthServiceRPCGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    }

    public TokenValidationResponseDTO validateToken(TokenValidationRequestDTO request) {
        return authServiceStub.validateToken(request);
    }
}
```

this is root pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>service2</module>
        <module>user</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>service project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  versions higher than 5.1.2 does not work-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- gRPC dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--Utils-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

So when I make maven clean install, maven plugin generates RPC service in target folder and Auth class with request/response dtos, but when I execute this command in service2, then it fails, because it cant find `rpc.Auth`. Seems intelij does not recognize user service target folder as source folder for service2, how to fix that?what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does Maven work from the command line? If not you can try the build-helper-maven-plugin: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin. Otherwise, go to the folder in the project tree, right click, and mark it as source directory. I'm not using IntelliJ right now so I can't give clearer instructions on the latter.

Comment: @RobSpoor yes  maven work from command line, I executed clean install manually and mvn protobuf:compile but no effect

Answer (score 0):

[How to add an extra source directory for maven to compile and include in the build jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui) has a nice discussion of this.

In latest version of maven this will be done automatically for you.

For older versions you can use:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>build/generated/source/proto/main/java</generatedSourcesDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```