# Maven generate-sources folder not being picked up by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I am in the process of migrating my build from Ant to Maven. The Ant build used to compile a "code generator", execute this "code generator" which produced a set of Java and C code. It then took the generated Java code and compiled it along with some additional code produce a single jar.

I have replicated this this in Maven quite easily and it works well when I run from the command line but Eclipse is complaining and is giving me an error relating to the pom file

> Failure to find {group.id}:{artifact.id}:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://{our internal site repository}/nexus/content/groups/public was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are
>   forced

where the group.id and artifact.id are the group and artifact id of my code generator plugin

and any code that references the generated code also fails to compile.

My maven build consists of

- a generator project that contains just the Java code for the code generator.
- a generator-plugin project that contains just the code to wrap the generator as a Maven plugin. This is dependent upon the generator project.
- an xyz project that uses the plugin to generate the code. The code ends up in the target/generated-sources/xxx folder of this project. I have configured the build-helper-maven-plugin as per [Maven compile with multiple src directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories) to include this extra source directory.

If I manually add the generated source folder to the Eclipse build path all of the errors relating to the code not being there go away on that project but not on any downstream projects and the "Failure to find..." error listed above remains.

What puzzles me a little is that it is referring to the ...:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT when in fact my generator-plugin is defined as a maven-plugin.

Is this a sensible approach?

Why am I getting a  "Failure to find..." error?

Why isn't Eclipse picking up my generated-sources folders?

I should also say I have the m2e plugin and the m2e connector for build-help-maven-plugin installed in my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Do you have a multi-module structure which contains your plugin, your generator code etc. into a single structure or do you have separated projects ?

Comment: Its a flat multi-module structure. Each module is imported into Eclipse as a separate project.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, if it runs fine from the command line (and you are running the terminal commands from the same directory eclipse is looking at) then your problem lies with eclipse or the eclipse plugin. 

However, it sounds like your eclipse setup is either misunderstanding what your generator plugin is or where to go to look for it (is there even a pom with version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on your repo, or just a jar?) It should be looking for it locally first anyways, so theoretically it should find it in your repo - however, if it's looking for a pom and finds a jar it will error.

Comment: Eclipse wants a m2e connector or a lifecycle mapping for any Maven plugins it uses.  Since you probably haven't written a connector for your custom plugin, consider defining a [mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) in your POM.

Comment: I think that's probably it I did have a lifecycle mapping but I included it as an xml file in my generator plugin. I thought I had the version of m2e that supported this as I had downloaded what I thought was the latest. Instead I had to put the lifecycle mapping in the pom file for the project that is using the generator plugin. This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem during the download of the lib from the repository. I already had the same error message once.

- Did you take a look at your local repository?

  Go to the .m2 folder and look for `/nexus/content/groups/public`. If the folder is there, open it and see if the lib was download correctly. If not, try to delete the folder and try to run `mvn install` to force the download of the lib.

  At Eclipse, run `Right button > Maven > Update Project` too.
- Are you using an local repository like Artifactory, aren't you? Also look for the lib in the `repo1-cache` (or similar) folder. See if the jar is there.
- Are you behind any firewall or proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Using eclipse Indigo3.7, this was what I found that worked good using spring 3.1.1 which does have the 3.0.6 version as well in it.  Once I got the plugins setup and put into the correct area of the pom and included the argline and endorseddirs to have the java sources put out into the target/generated-sources/cxf folder then maven generated the sources ok.

....

```
 <properties>...

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>.....
   </dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>....

</dependencies>



<!-- *************************** Build process ************************************* -->
<build>
    <finalName>projName</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Force Java 6 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Deployent on AS from console
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.as.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
        -->

        <!-- wildbill added tomcat plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>              
        </plugin>

        <!-- Surefire plugin before 2.9 version is buggy. No need to declare here,
              it's being referenced below w/ the version
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </plugin>
        -->

        <!-- developer added these -->   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>target/generated-sources/cxf</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=target/generated-sources/cxf</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>target/generated-sources/cxf</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=target/generated-sources/cxf</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>                       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>                       
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/cxf</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>                      
        </plugin>                                                 
    </plugins>
</build>



<!-- *********************** Profiles ************************************ -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be 
            used when invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization 
            your app will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 
            'deployments' folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>projName</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>                                                   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>                        
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>                                                                                               
                            <configuration>
                                <fork>once</fork>
                                <additionalJvmArgs>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=target/generated-sources/cxf</additionalJvmArgs>                                          
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>                             
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>                       
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                           <version>2.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                           <version>2.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                     </dependencies>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Actual war created in default target dir -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                                     <version>2.2</version>                                               
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

If your wsdl folder is in ${basedir}/src/main/resources it'll find it automatically

Hope this helps!