# Maven Thrift Plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, thrift

I am trying to automate the generation of source files from the `.thrift` files and later the packaging. As far as I know, the `maven-thrift-plugin` is restrictive in the sense that source and destination directories are fixed. Is there any way I can specify the source and destination directories? I could probably achieve this by using the `maven-antrun-plugin` but I don't want to pollute my pom unnecessarily if I don't have to.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd bet there is already an answer around, but I don't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from the source (https://github.com/dtrott/maven-thrift-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/thrift/maven/ThriftCompileMojo.java) there are configuration properties that control this behaviour.

Try these properties, they should work:

- `thriftSourceRoot`
- `thriftTestSourceRoot`
- `outputDirectory`

These props should be added to the `<configuration>` section along with `<thriftExecutable>`, etc:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-thrift-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <thriftExecutable>/usr/local/bin/thrift</thriftExecutable>
        <thriftSourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/my_custom_thrift_root</thriftSourceRoot>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. This indeed generates the source files into the directory I specify. However, it creates

Comment: Thanks! This indeed generates the source files into the directory I specify. However, it creates these files in a gen-java directory which I cannot seem to get rid of. Additionally, the plugin will force-clean the output directory which is also a bit of a problem for me as I have other helper classes in the directory and they get deleted as well. Is there any way I can avoid the force-cleanup?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get rid of `gen-java` (at least I couldn't do it even in command line). Speaking of force-clean: multiple java files might be generated from a single thrift source. So, the junk generated files will appear after every rename of a `struct`/`service` in thrift source. It's better to generate other files in different directories.

Comment: I feared as much. I'll see if I can use the `maven-antrun-plugin` after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also ended up going the `maven-antrun-plugin` route, here is a functional example: https://github.com/cobbzilla/cobbzilla-wizard/tree/master/wizard-thrift

- pom.xml uses `maven-antrun-plugin` to exec the `thrift` target in build.xml
- build.xml does the thrift compilation and packaging.

Generated sources go back into the source tree; I don't like derived files polluting my upstream source control, so the generated files are under a `thrift` package, and the package directory is in a `.gitignore` file. A bit kludgy.

A better way I learned about since writing that code is [to compile multiple java source directories in a single maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories), which would be cleaner.