# Converting a project to maven - dealing with additional source directories

Tags: java, maven

I'm converting a legacy Java project to Maven. It currently uses Ant, and has a structure like this:

`src\mainProduct\com\mycompany`
`src\external\com\acme\...`

Assuming I move everything under `src\mainProduct` into the Maven-structure (`src\main\java`), is there a way to include the `external` folder as an additional source directory without moving it? Alternatively, how do I move it under `src\main\java\external`, without changing the package names?

Comment: Just make your "external" sources an artifact on their own (or a module within your project).

Comment: Best idea is to make those as external into a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

So what you'd have to do is:

```
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>src/mainProduct</sourceDirectory>
   ...
</build>
```

Alternatively you could try and use the approach suggested here: [Maven compile with multiple src directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories)

The build-helper-plugin and its documentation can be found here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

if you move it, move it to `src\external\java`, that might be better suited than `src\main\java\external`. 
[Maven compile with multiple src directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories) shows how to add additional source directories to be used by Maven.