# How do I export all the generated with cxg-codegen-plugin classes from a Java 9 module?

Tags: java, java-9, java-10, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I've got a module without any explicit sources. This module contains the following cxf-codegen-plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/schema/wsdl/service.wsdl
                                </wsdl>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>
                                        ${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xml
                                    </bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

So it is a dependency with generated classes. I need to export all the classes to other Java modules. Let's say, I need to export `com.company.team.app` package. I tried adding it to `module-info.java` but it doesn't compile because it says (which is valid actually):

> module-info.java:[6,20] package is empty or does not exist:
>   com.company.team.app

How do I export this classes then? Thank you very much!

Comment: Compile the module-info.java after all classes have been generated.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn interesting idea, do you have an idea of how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compile` phase [comes after](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) `generate-sources`, so unless you see that error message *before the `compile` phase* (that would be weird!), the sources are already generated.

Here's what I would do in your situation:

- Make sure the sources are actually generated. ~> Do you see them in the file system after `mvn clean compile`?
- Make sure the folder is included in the sources to compile. ~> Run `mvn compile -X` and look out for the message block starting with "Source roots" - the folder needs to be mentioned there. (If it is not, [add it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/270490/2525313).)
- Make sure the package name is correct, i.e. the generated package names and the exported package name must be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it works. I didn't know that I can't specify a package without sources, I thought it will resolve all the classes recursively. But that doesn't make sense actually. Specifying the exact packages containing compiled classes did help. Hope it helps someone!