# How to modify Java / Swift Source code during build time

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, feature-selection

Let say I have

```
Code 1 // for customer A

Code 2  // for Customer B

code 3  // Shared code
```

I want to modify the source code during build time so that the source code for 1 or 2 is removed completely base on some build-time parameters.

any library out there? 
I don't want to use a bash script with 'sed'.

Edit: This is for a iOS and Android building

Comment: This is indicative that you haven't properly modularized your code. All of your shared code should be in a separate library, called upon from the ClientA and ClientB applications.

Comment: I think most build tools can do this. For Maven you can for example use different src directories: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories which you can set the source path dynamically or copy the needed sources into.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an excellent application for a `Makefile` ...

https://github.com/therealglazou/swift-makefiles

http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2016/02/19/A-makefile-based-build-system-for-Swift

As you well know, the Unix/Linux `make` command is specifically designed for easily specifying features to include or exclude during a build-process.