# Test cases in new folder created parallel to src/test/java in latest Eclipse IDE maven java project is not executing the test cases

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I have a simple java maven project in Eclipse Neon. The project structure looks like

```
 MyProject
  |
   - src/main/java
   - src/main/resources
   - src/test/java
   - src/test/resources
   - src/feature01test   << A set of test cases, few class depends on src/test/java classes >>
```

With Eclipse Neon, i was able to debug the junit classes locally for the test cases present in `src/feature01test`.

With New Eclipse version (version 2019-03), i am NOT able to run the test cases within the `src/feature01test`.

I added this folder to the Project source, by Project Name -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source tab -> Add Folder -> choose src/feature01test folder.

Below is the exception message: (note class name are not exact class name i used)

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=myCustomTestCase01], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=myCustomTestCase01(com.test.TestCaseOne)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.test.TestCaseOne,fLeadingIdentifier=myCustomTestCase01]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@4b6995df
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

using java 1.8.0_181 version.

Is there any way to run the java test cases present in a directory structure parallel to src/test?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Maven, add source directories by configuring the pom.xml, not by adding source directories in the project properties.

Look at the following for more about this: [Maven compile with multiple src directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories) .